# Java 8 streams and varargs

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, variadic-functions

According to *Effective Java 2nd Ed*, when you want to write a method signature that allows for varargs but still enforces that you have one element minimum at compile-time you should write the method signature this way:

```
public void something(String required, String ... additional) {
    //... do what you want to do
}
```

If I want to stream all these elements, I've been doing something like this:

```
public void something(String required, String ... additional) {
    Stream<String> allParams =
        Stream.concat(Stream.of(required), Stream.of(additional));
    //... do what you want to do
}
```

This feels really inelegant and wasteful, especially because I'm creating a stream of 1 and concatenating it with another. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: `Stream.concat` seems fine to me...it's short, concise, it doesn't create copies of the data. You're creating a few extra wrapper objects, that's all. IMO really nothing wrong with it. Programming in Java, you just have to create small objects for things here and there. `Stream.concat` is already miles ahead of merging them with an `ArrayList` or something like that.

Comment: I agree with Radiodef, if you really wanted to you could make your own implementation of `Spliterator<T>` and use it with `StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, parallel)` but i really dont feel like that makes it any more readable or efficient.

Comment: I think this title is not concrete.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a way for doing it without creating two `Streams`, although you might not like it.

```
Stream.Builder<String> builder = Stream.<String>builder().add(required);
for (String s : additional) {
  builder.add(s);
}

Stream<String> allParams = builder.build();
```

Comment: You may also replace for-loop with `Stream.of(additional).forEach(builder);`

Comment: Upon revisiting this and based on the comments, my original way seems fine. However, this answer seems to be the best alternative given my previous view. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong with the composed streams. These objects are lightweight as they only refer to the source data but don’t copy data like array contents. The cost of such lightweight object might only be relevant if the actual payload is very small as well. Such scenarios can be handled with specialized, semantically equivalent overloads:

```
public void something(String required, String ... additional) {
    somethingImpl(Stream.concat(Stream.of(required), Stream.of(additional)));
}
public void something(String required) {
    somethingImpl(Stream.of(required));
}
public void something(String required, String second) {
    somethingImpl(Stream.of(required, second));
}
private void somethingImpl(Stream<String> allParams) {
    //... do what you want to do
}
```

so in the case of only one argument you’re not only saving `Stream` instances but also the varargs array (similar to `Stream.of`’s overload). This is a common pattern, see for example the `EnumSet.of` overloads.

However, in a lot of cases even these simple overloads are not necessary and might be considered premature optimization (libraries like the JRE offer them as it’s otherwise impossible for an application developer to add them if ever needed). If `something` is part of an application rather than a library you shouldn’t add them unless a profiler tells you that there’s a bottleneck caused by that parameter processing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use Guava, you may `Lists.asList(required, additional).stream()`. The method was created to ease that varargs with minimum requirement idiom.

A side note, I consider the library really useful, but of course it's not a good idea to add it just because of that. Check the [docs](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki) and see if it could be of more use to you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Java can be quite verbose. But another option to alleviate that is to simply use static imports. In my opinion, it does not make your code less clear since every method is stream-related.

```
Stream<String> allParams =
    concat(of(required), of(additional));
```

Comment: I personally don't like static imports - it's just one more mechanism that gets in the way of knowing where something came from (in this case the static function).

Answer (score 2):

Third-party extensions to Stream API like my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) or [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) provide methods like `append` or `prepend` which allow you to do this in more clean way:

```
// Using StreamEx
Stream<String> allParams = StreamEx.of(required).append(additional);
// Using jOOL
Stream<String> allParams = Seq.of(required).append(additional);
```